# Spring @Cacheable how to deal with Redis Read and Read / Write replicas?

Tags: spring, caching, redis, read-write

I have a simple method that connects to an external service and I want to cache its result

```
  @Cacheable(cacheNames = "myCache", key = "#token")
  public String getUserByToken(String token) {
    return externalService.getUserFromToken(token);
  }
```

Right now this is my custom CacheManager config because i need different TTL for different cache key.

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfiguration extends CachingConfig {

  @Autowired
  private LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory;

  @Primary
  @Bean
  public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    RedisCacheConfiguration redisCacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig();
    CacheManager cacheManager = RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder.fromConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory)
      .cacheDefaults(redisCacheConfiguration)
      .withCacheConfiguration("myCache",
        redisCacheConfiguration.entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(5)))
      .withCacheConfiguration("someOtherCache",
        redisCacheConfiguration.entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(10)))
      .build();

    return cacheManager;
  }
```

Right now I have a single `lettuceConnectionFactory` which is simply the bean created by Spring AutoConfigure stuff and uses my Redis primary Read / Write endpoint.

However I would like to improve throughput and planning to create 2 separate lettuce connection factory bean. One that will use my Redis primary read / write endpoint and an other `lettuceReadConnectionFactory` that will use my Redis read only endpoint.

I would like to use the lettuceReadConnectionFactory exclusively for read operation.

Is there a way somehow to still use `@Cacheable` and have it use a different cacheManager to read and write ?

Answer (score 0):

The `@Cacheable` annotation takes a `cacheManager` attribute, you could create two different named `CacheManager` beans and pass your customized managers to it.